# Semantic-UI React Checkbox state not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, semantic-ui

I've got a parent container that calls a class-based react component child (since the semantic-ui react docs are all written with class-based components). The child component has a `Form.Field`:

```
<Form.Field 
    control={Checkbox} 
    label={{children: 'cardreader'}}
    checked = {this.state.cardReaderChecked}                
    onChange={this.cardReaderToggleHandler}
/>
```

I've got a `state`:

```
state = {
    cardReaderChecked: false,     
}
```

and a `cardReaderToggleHandler`:

```
cardReaderToggleHandler = () => {
    console.log(this.state.cardReaderChecked);
    this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
        cardReaderChecked : !prevState.cardReaderChecked
    }))
console.log(this.state.cardReaderChecked);
}
```

I've tried toggling on `this.state.cardReaderChecked` but I found a lot of references and docs recommending this approach with the `prevState` to avoid the delay in state updating.

However, there must a logical fault because it doesn't work. If I refresh the page, the `checkbox` is clear as `this.state.cardReaderChecked`.

The first time I click the `checkbox` it renders with the tick, and my `this.state.cardReaderChecked` updates to `true` (according to my trusty React tools in Chrome). However, both `console.log` printouts give me a `false` and if I pass my `state` back to the parent form, it also shows that the checkbox is false.

Every subsequent click toggles but a ticked `checkbox` shows a `true` state but passes on a `false` to the parent form (that's where the `console.log` is currently) and vice versa an unticked `checkbox` passes back a `true`.

I'm almost tempted to remove the `not` from the `prev.state` in the `setState`, but I would prefer to understand why this happens.

Bonus Question: How can I query the `checkbox` state `checked` in a functional component?

Comment: do this `console.log(this.state.cardReaderChecked);` inside `.setState()` callback

Comment: `cardReaderToggleHandler = () => {
    console.log(this.state.cardReaderChecked);
    this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
        cardReaderChecked : !prevState.cardReaderChecked
    }), () => console.log(this.state.cardReaderChecked))
}`

Comment: @JuniusL.. I completely forgot I can do a callback there. Ok, the callback is always the opposite of the state... (well, the state *outside*)

Comment: the value doe change right?

Comment: @JuniusL. Yes, it does... cool... I use the callback. Thank you!

Comment: where is `cardReaderToggleHandler`? in child or parent?

Comment: @JuniusL. in the child

Comment: and you want to update the value in parent?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194160/discussion-between-4ndy-and-junius-l).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the function to a child as prop

```
class Parent extends Component {

  state = {
    cardReaderChecked: false,
  }

  cardReaderToggleHandler = () => {

    this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
      cardReaderChecked : !prevState.cardReaderChecked
    }), () => console.log(this.state.cardReaderChecked))
  }
  ....

  render () {
    return (
     ....
     <Form.Field 
       control={Checkbox} 
       label={{children: 'cardreader'}}
       checked = {this.state.cardReaderChecked}                
       onChange={this.cardReaderToggleHandler}
     />
    )
  }
```